# Webpack raw-loader errors out when require markdown file

Tags: javascript, webpack, markdown, raw-loader

`raw-loader` errors out when attempting to require any `.md` file.

Adding raw loader to import markdown files:

```
  test: /\.md$/i,
      use: [{
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        options: {
          esModule: false
        }
      }],
```

In `.js` file, require the markdown file..

```
return require(postPath)
// postPath is '../posts/awards.md'
```

```
Error: Cannot find module '../posts/awards.md'
at webpackEmptyContext (eval at <path to file>)
....
```

the path to markdown file is the relative path: `/posts/awards.md`

If I change `awards.md` to `awards.json` it works. So maybe it is an issue with `raw-loader` looking for a `export` in `awards.md` and not find one, thus erroring out? Isn't the point of `esModule: false` to instruct Webpack to NOT treat it as module?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're having the same problem as [this person.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680)

Quoting an answer:

> Webpack performs a static analyse at build time.
>
> It doesn't try to infer variables which that import(test) could be anything, hence the failure.
>
> It is also the case for import(path+"a.js").
>
> **If you need truly dynamic imports, you have to restrict it to a known path:**
>
> `import("./locales/" + locale + ".js")`

I re-created your problem and sure enough:

```
function test(mod) {
    return require(mod)
}

console.log(test("./test.md"))
```

Doesn't work. **HOWEVER** this works:

```
function test(mod) {
    return require("./" + mod)
}

console.log(test("test.md"))
```

So it should suffice to change your code to this:

```
return require("../" + postPath + ".md")
```

And change `postPath` to:

```
// postPath is 'posts/awards'
```

Comment: Would be even better if OP left the file extension out of the variable. That way, `require(\`../${postPath}.md\`)` would tell Webpack to only bundle all `.md` files